# How to find minimum and maximum rate in Yii using Statistical or Relational query

Tags: php, mysql, yii, phpmyadmin

I need to display the maximum rate and minimum proposal rate along with count of proposals for each request that is posted by a logged in user using Statistical/ Relational Query. I am getting the count or minimum rate using the relation

```
public function relations()
 {
  return array('serviceproposals'=>
                       array(self::HAS_MANY,'Serviceproposal','ServiceRequestID'),
                  'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Buyer', 'user_id'),
                  'postCount'=>array(self::STAT,'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID','select'=>'MAX(proposal_rate)'),

  );
 }
```

Database used contains:-

```
User[user_id,name,password],
Provider[user_id,providercompany,providerdetails],
Buyer[user_id,contactinfo],
ServiceRequest[ServiceRequestID,Buyer.user_id,details,date],
ServiceProposal[ServiceProposalId,ServiceRequestID,Provider.user_id,services,propsal_rate]
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of my mistake that I am not getting count, maximum and minimum rate. There needs to provide 2 separate relations so the 3 values are getting well.

```
return array(

   'serviceproposals' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID'),
   'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Buyer', 'user_id'),
                        'postCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID'),
                        'maxvalue'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID','select'=>'MAX(proposal_amount)'),
                        'minvalue'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID','select'=>'MIN(proposal_amount)'),

  );
 }
```